# NSURLErrorDomain 503 - Service Unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I have an iPad app which was built and archived by Xcode5.1. But, it runs on iOS7 - iOS10. It was all working fine until today. When we tried syncing with Salesforce, it started throwing service unavailable error with error code 503. It happens when we try to sync data from Salesforce and its not happening during syncing the same object. It is throwing this error randomly. Any ideas on what this error might be..? Thanks!

Comment: Since it's a 5xx error, obviously the problem is not on your end.

Comment: @Desdenova - Thanks for your reply.. What is the exact message, it is trying to give here..? Because, salesforce in browsers are working fine.